# sequentially merging based on 4 possible match criteria in R

Tags: r, merge

I have a dataframe called `reference`, which has two fields, `trait1` and `trait2` I would like to merge into another dataframe, `to_assign`. Both `reference` and `to_assign`, have two identifier columns, `id.1` and `id.2`. I would like to perform the following merge:

1. Merge together using the `id.1` columns.
2. For all entries still unassigned, merge on `to_assign$id.1` and `reference$id.2`
3. For all entries still unassigned, merge on `to_assign$id.2` and `reference$id.1`
4. For all entries still unassigned, merge on `to_assign$id.2` and `reference$id.2`

Here is code to generate these data frames:

```
id.1 <- LETTERS[1:10]
id.2 <- LETTERS[6:15]
trait1 <- rbinom(length(id.1),1,0.5)
trait2 <- rbinom(length(id.1),1,0.5)
reference <- data.frame(id.1,id.2,trait1,trait2)

id.1 <- LETTERS[runif(100,1,26)]
id.2 <- LETTERS[runif(100,1,26)]
to_assign <- data.frame(id.1,id.2)
```

I can do this by performing the first merge, subsetting assigned and unassigned entries, deleting columns `trait.1` and `trait.2` from `unassigned`, repeating the merge between `unassigned` and `reference` using the second merge criterion, and then calling `rbind(assigned,unassigned)`, rinse and repeat for merge criteria 3 and 4. Here is code to do just this, and this generates my desired output as `out`:

```
#merge 1.
out <- merge(to_assign, reference[,c('id.1','trait1','trait2')], all.x=T)
#merge 2.
  assigned <- out[!is.na(out$trait1),]
unassigned <- out[ is.na(out$trait1),]
unassigned$trait1 <- NULL
unassigned$trait2 <- NULL
unassigned <- merge(unassigned, reference[,c('id.2','trait1','trait2')], by.x = 'id.1', by.y='id.2', all.x=T)
out <- rbind(assigned, unassigned)
#merge 3.
  assigned <- out[!is.na(out$trait1),]
unassigned <- out[ is.na(out$trait1),]
unassigned$trait1 <- NULL
unassigned$trait2 <- NULL
unassigned <- merge(unassigned, reference[,c('id.1','trait1','trait2')], by.x = 'id.2', by.y='id.1', all.x=T)
out <- rbind(assigned, unassigned)
#merge 4.
  assigned <- out[!is.na(out$trait1),]
unassigned <- out[ is.na(out$trait1),]
unassigned$trait1 <- NULL
unassigned$trait2 <- NULL
unassigned <- merge(unassigned, reference[,c('id.2','trait1','trait2')], all.x=T)   
out <- rbind(assigned, unassigned)
```

However, this seems like a total headache, and I have a lot of reference dataframes I need to merge this way. I am looking for a way to do this that is more straightforward and will not require ~20 lines of code per reference dataframe merge. I'm having trouble writing a function to do this, as the function would need to handle reference dataframes that can have different column names than `trait1` and `trait2`, and potentially more than 2.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would work for you, using my package [`safejoin`](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin), which wraps functions from packages `dplyr` and `fuzzyjoin` :

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)
debugonce(safe_left_join)
res <- safe_left_join(to_assign, reference, check ="", ~
                 X("id.1") == Y("id.1") | 
                 X("id.1") == Y("id.2") |
                 X("id.2") == Y("id.1") |
                 X("id.2") == Y("id.2"))

head(res,15)
#    id.1.x id.2.x id.1.y id.2.y trait1 trait2
# 1       J      O      E      J      0      0
# 2       J      O      J      O      0      0
# 3       C      A      A      F      0      1
# 4       C      A      C      H      0      0
# 5       C      W      C      H      0      0
# 6       C      L      C      H      0      0
# 7       C      L      G      L      0      1
# 8       I      W      D      I      0      1
# 9       I      W      I      N      1      0
# 10      C      C      C      H      0      0
# 11      L      E      E      J      0      0
# 12      L      E      G      L      0      1
# 13      W      S   <NA>   <NA>     NA     NA
# 14      P      S   <NA>   <NA>     NA     NA
# 15      T      D      D      I      0      1
```

`check=""` makes it quiet, as by default *safejoin* doesn't like conflicting columns

Answer (score 0):

Here is one potential function that returns the same result as the ~20 lines of code in the question above. However, it is not the prettiest function, and I am still looking for a better solution.

```
super_merge <- function(d1, d2, merge.columns = c('id.1','id.2')){
  ref_names <- colnames(d2)[!(colnames(d2) %in% merge.columns)]
  #merge 1.
  out <- merge(d1,d2[, !(colnames(d2) %in% merge.columns[2])], all.x=T)
  #merge 2.
  to_check <- colnames(out)[colnames(out) %in% ref_names[1]]
    assigned <- out[!is.na(out[,to_check]),]
  unassigned <- out[ is.na(out[,to_check]),]
  unassigned[,ref_names] = NULL
  unassigned <- merge(unassigned,d2[, !(colnames(d2) %in% merge.columns[1])], 
                      by.x = merge.columns[1], by.y = merge.columns[2], all.x = T)
  out <- rbind(assigned,unassigned)
  #merge 3.
  assigned <- out[!is.na(out[,to_check]),]
  unassigned <- out[ is.na(out[,to_check]),]
  unassigned[,ref_names] = NULL
  unassigned <- merge(unassigned,d2[, !(colnames(d2) %in% merge.columns[2])], 
                      by.x = merge.columns[2], by.y = merge.columns[1], all.x = T)
  out <- rbind(assigned,unassigned)
  #merge 4.
  assigned <- out[!is.na(out[,to_check]),]
  unassigned <- out[ is.na(out[,to_check]),]
  unassigned[,ref_names] = NULL
  unassigned <- merge(unassigned,d2[, !(colnames(d2) %in% merge.columns[1])], 
                      by.x = merge.columns[2], by.y = merge.columns[2], all.x = T)
  out <- rbind(assigned,unassigned)
  #return output.
  return(out)
}
```

Excecute the function as:

```
output <- super_merge(to_assign,reference,merge.columns=c('id.1','id.2'))
```